# Is it possible to upgrade kernel of 14.04 LTS to v4.1.6(stable release)?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel

I am using ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit, 2GB RAM) and kernel is v3.18.3-031803-generic. Is it possible to upgrade the kernel version to latest kernel v4.1.6 without any issues?

Comment: Why do you want to upgrade ?

Comment: Actually i am encountering wifi connection issue. For resolution, upgrade to latest kernel is suggested. That is why i am considering to latest kernel release.

Comment: There is a 4.1.6 LTS Kernel. Official page instructions are https://ubuntuportal.com/2015/08/kernel-4-1-6-lts-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not recommended because it is not supported in current stable Ubuntu version (no security update etc...).

Run the following commands :

**64 bits :**

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.6-unstable/linux-headers-4.1.6-040106_4.1.6-040106.201508170230_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.6-unstable/linux-headers-4.1.6-040106-generic_4.1.6-040106.201508170230_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.6-unstable/linux-image-4.1.6-040106-generic_4.1.6-040106.201508170230_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.1.6*.deb linux-image-4.1.6*.deb
```

**32 bits : (your case)**

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.6-unstable/linux-headers-4.1.6-040106_4.1.6-040106.201508170230_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.6-unstable/linux-headers-4.1.6-040106-generic_4.1.6-040106.201508170230_i386.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.6-unstable/linux-image-4.1.6-040106-generic_4.1.6-040106.201508170230_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.1.6*.deb linux-image-4.1.6*.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

The 4.1.6 LTS Kernel would be a good choice.

The instructions are here:
https://ubuntuportal.com/2015/08/kernel-4-1-6-lts-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

Possible but highly recommended against. That puts the system in an inconsistent state. See [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) for details.